# MySQL Structure for this type of content?

Tags: mysql, structure

I have a couple hundred text files that have data that looks like:

```
Capo: 77/100
Define: 0/70
Largo: 85/85
Facto: 16/75
```

**Would a database be appropriate for this?** If it is, I can't think of a way to properly structure a table.

One might think to make columns for `Capo`, `Define`, `Largo`, and `Facto` but across these several hundred text files there are about a *200 different words*, that would each require a column if that were to be done.

Comment: Do these 4 values belong together? If so, how are they related? And what is the relation with those 200 other words? In fact, what do they mean? Are they musical terms?

Comment: I think we need more information on the sort of data stored in those files in order to provide more feedback. It seems that you might be looking at a key value type of store, but does that keys and values in the other files have totally unique key names or are there some that would conflict?

Comment: @GolezTrol the 4 values are not related to each other, but to the term next to it. IE 77/100 is Capo's value.

Comment: In that case, just store them in a table that has a column 'Name' and a column 'Value'.

Comment: @GolezTrol wouldn't that render it impossible then to do a comparative query, something like: `WHERE 'Value' > 78/100?`

Comment: Why? Maybe you need to split up value in two numbers, so you can write `WHERE Num1/Num2 > 78/100, but we still don't know what these values mean and what you need to do with them, so everything we say is still a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store them in a kind of key/value structure, like this;

```
Values:
Key    v1  v2
-------------
Capo    0 166
Largo  77  77
Facto  10  20
```

If they relate to each other, you can give those values a parent id to group them:

```
Values:
Parent Key    v1  v2
---------------------
0      Capo    0 166
0      Largo  77  77
0      Facto  10  20
1      Capo    5  88
```

If the words are fixed, you could normalize them to a different table:

```
Words:
WordID  Word
------------
1       Capo
2       Largo
3       Facto
4       Define

Values:
Parent WordId v1  v2
---------------------
0      1       0 166
0      2      77  77
0      3      10  20
1      1       5  88
```

As an alternative, you may want to look like a storage like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design). It allows you to store 'documents' which each have different properties.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know exactly what these data mean without a better explanation.  But it's not hard to stick all this stuff in a DBMS table.  Create columns that show

1. Word
2. Numerator
3. Denominator
4. File  name (for the text file from which the file came).

Then you can process and aggregate the words with queries like this.

```
SELECT word,
       SUM(numerator)   AS numerator,
       SUM(denominator) AS denominator
  FROM words
 GROUP BY word
```

Go fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0e4d/1/0

Answer (score 1):

Given your above format, I would create the structure below. The primary key is the word, meaning it can only show up once. I am assuming that the two values do not exceed `100`, therefore a `tinyint` column will be sufficient.

```
CREATE TABLE words (
  word varchar(15) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  val1 tinyint UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
  val2 tinyint UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0)
```

If you will have multiple occurrences of the word, you may consider to add a surrogate key to be the primary key such as:

```
CREATE TABLE words (
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  word varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  val1 tinyint UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
  val2 tinyint UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0)
```